# PayPal Get Customer Approval Process unclear

Tags: api, paypal

I'm working on a PayPal Subscriptions integration. As usual, the PayPal documentation is indescribably bad.

As part of the process, you are required to "Get Customer Approval" - I understand how this works (you redirect the customer to a URL that is in a response received earlier in the process).

According to PayPal, you have to execute the agreement AFTER the customer has approved. There is no mention whatsoever of how PayPal communicates the fact of approval:

> The customer approves, and subscribes to, the agreement and enters his
>   or her customer and payment details. After you get the customer and
>   payment details, you can execute the agreement. Then, it becomes an
>   active subscription.

Can anybody shed light on how this is achieved?